# c# - Validar previa a conversión de dato

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un proceso de leer XML y vaciarlos en un `List<ClasePOCO>`, para lo cual utilizo lo siguiente (ejemplo una linea)

```
 oTarjetaL.datUltimaCarga = DateTime.ParseExact(tarjeta.SelectSingleNode("FELULTCARGA").InnerText, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
```

Bueno la consulta es ¿cómo aplicar una validación en la cual, en caso de no existir en nodo, tener un formato erróneo o cual cualquier otro problema de la conversión, le asigne un valor por defaul, ya sea null o lo que uno defina?

Estaba pensando algo como:

```
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)
```

Pero ahí no se puede especificar el formato de conversión y/o que valor por defecto asignaría.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un conversor genérico para la ocasión:

```
class Parser
{
  public static void Convert<T>(string input, out T output, T defaultValue )
  {
    try
    {
      var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
      if(converter != null)
        output = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
      else
        output = defaultValue;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      output = defaultValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
int val1, val2;
Parser.Convert("1000",out val1, 5);
Parser.Convert("10dd00",out val2, 5);
Console.WriteLine(val1 + " " + val2);
```

Salida:

```
1000 5
```

Comment: Eso ni lo imaginé, esta super, si no fuera mucha molestia, como puedo enganchar el hecho de que el XML tenga o no tenga un determinado nodo, ya que si accedo cada nodo lo mandaria a ese conversor, pero si no existe el nodo simplemente no funcuionaría.

Comment: Con eso estarías sobrecargando a la función de responsabilidades y esa no es buena idea teniendo en cuenta el mantenimiento futuro. Lo que sí podrias hacer es una nueva función que cogiese ese nodo y que intente el parseo únicamente si es válido. ¿Cómo hacer eso? bueno, es algo que empieza a depender demasiado de tu código... la solución adecuada depende del diseño de tu código actual.